# PHP switch case default

Tags: php, switch-statement, default

Will the default of a switch statement get evaluated if there's a matching case before it?

ex:

```
switch ($x) {
  case ($x > 5): print "foo";
  case ($x%2 == 0): print "bar";
  default: print "nope";
}
```

so for x = 50, you'd see `foo` and `bar`, or `foo` and `bar` and `nope`?

Comment: Did you try running this code?

Comment: If there is no case match, the default case will be executed.

Comment: FYI `case ($x > 5)` evaluates to `case 1:` or `case true:`.

Comment: Without `break` your code will try to match all conditions. With `break` it'll stop at the 1st match.

Comment: I don't want it to stop at the first match. I want it to execute code for all matching cases.

Comment: Without breaks in your code, it will execute the first matching case and every case thereafter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, if there is no "break", then all actions following the first `case` matched will be executed. The control flow will "falls through" all subsequent `case`, and execute all of the actions  under each subsequent `case`, until a `break;` statement is encountered, or until the end of the `switch` statement is reached.

In your example, if $x has a value of 50, you would actually see `"nope"`.

Note that `switch` is actually performing a simple equality test, between the expression following the `switch` keyword, and each expression following the `case` keyword.

Your example is unusual, in that it will only display `"foo"` when $x has a value of 0. (Actually, when $x has a value of 0, what you would see would be "foo bar nope".)

The expression following the `case` keyword is evaluated, which in your case, example return a 0 (if the conditional test is false) or a 1 (if the conditional test is true). And it's that value (0 or 1) that `switch` will compare to `$x`.

Answer (score 6):

> Will the default of a switch statement get evaluated if there's a matching case before it?

In most `case`s it shouldn't, because you would often have `break`s in there. However in your case it would also go to the `default`.

Also please try to prevent to do those single line stuff (for readability):

```
$x = 10;

switch (true) {
  case ($x > 5):
      print "foo";

  case ($x%2 == 0):
      print "bar";

  default:
      print "nope";
}
```

Will print `foobarnope`. So to answer your question: yep :-)

Comment: prints `foobarnope`. Soon as any case is true, all following cases, including default, up to a break (or end of switch) will run. http://codepad.viper-7.com/sjHYeZ

Answer (score 3):

That's not how switches work.

[According to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the
>   same expression. In many occasions, you may want to compare the same
>   variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a
>   different piece of code depending on which value it equals to. This is
>   exactly what the switch statement is for.

An evaluation like

```
case ($x > 5):
```

simply equates to

```
case true:
```

or

```
case false:
```

depending on the value of `$x` because `($x > 5)` is an *EVALUATION*, not a *VALUE*. Switches compare the value of the parameter to see if it equates to any of the `case`s.

```
switch($x) {
    case ($x > 5): // $x == ($x > 5)
        echo "foo";
        break;
    case ($x <= 5): // $x == ($x <= 5)
        echo "bar"
        break;
    default:
        echo "default";
        break;
}
```

The comparison in the above code is equivalent to

```
if ($x == ($x > 5)) {
    echo "foo";
} elseif ($x == ($x < 5)) {
    echo "bar";
} else {
    echo "five";
}
```

which (when `$x == 50`) is equivalent to

```
if ($x == true) {
    echo "foo";
} elseif ($x == false) {
    echo "bar";
} else {
    echo "five";
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (true) { // $x == true is the same as saying "$x is truthy"
    echo "foo";
} elseif (false) {
    echo "bar";
} else {
    echo "five";
}
```

**IF**, however, you used your switch statement as it is intended to be used (to compare the parameter to concrete values):

```
switch ($x) {
    case 50:
        echo "foo ";
    case 30:
        echo "bar ";
    default:
        echo "foo-bar";
}
```

and `$x == 50`, your output would be

```
foo bar foo-bar
```

due to the fact that you have no `break` in your cases.

Had you added the `break` keyword to the end of each case, you would only execute the code for that specific case.

```
switch ($x) {
    case 50:
        echo "foo ";
        break;
    case 30:
        echo "bar ";
        break;
    default:
        echo "foo-bar";
        break;
}
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Comment: No, you didn't. Read what you wrote. You said that you **can't** use switches "like that", and you are wrong - you can, and nothing prevents anyone from doing so. Posting a half-correct answer is horrible, someone will walk in and read what you wrote and think you were right when you weren't.

Comment: The OP's switch statement perfectly valid.  Having evaluations in cases is perfectly valid and highly desirable code.  Your answer only shows one type of use of the statement.

Comment: @Matt - there's nothing wrong behind the logic you're trying to explain, what's wrong is your explanation of the `switch` statement. Switch statement behaves exactly like an `if` statement. You can compare values in order to get a `true` or `false`. `switch` is just a convenience invented so one doesn't have to type 100 if/else combinations and nest the code to oblivion.

Comment: @buggabill I'm not so sure it's *highly desirable* but it is valid. My point was that it shouldn't be used in that fashion **unless it's fully understood why it's being used.**

Comment: @N.B. So are you saying that `case ($x > 5)` is the same as `if ($x > 5)`? Because it isn't. It equates to `if ($x == ($x > 5))` and OP needs to know that.

Comment: @Matt - well, I'm sorry but you're wrong. A `switch` statement behaves exactly like an `if`. `case $x > 50:` is exactly like `if($x > 50)` and that's that.

Comment: @N.B. my answer was in response to OP's final question: `so for x = 50, you'd see foo and bar, or foo and bar and nope?` Clearly, she doesn't understand how comparisons are done in a `switch` and I'm pretty sure this answer helped clarify that.

Comment: @N.B. [Show me in the documentation where a `switch` behaves like that and I'll give you a free 500 point bounty.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: @N.B. *"The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the same expression. In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a different piece of code depending on which value it equals to. This is exactly what the switch statement is for."*

Comment: @N.B. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904754/switch-evaluations Hopefully the answer to this question will settle this argument of ours. If I'm wrong, I'll remove my answer and award you 500 bounty. If I'm correct, I expect you to remove your comments and your -1.

Comment: @N.B., @Matt is exactly right about how the switch works. if you had a switch of `switch($x){ case 0: echo "hi"; break; }` wouldn't the equivalent if statement be `if($x == 0)...`? so then why wouldn't the OP's switch not be equal to `if($x == ($x > 5))...`? do you somehow lose the case equation?

Comment: @Matt, one line though I don't agree with. "The output for the above code would always be default unless $x == 1". This untrue. In the comparison `$x==($x > 5)` for example, there is an implicit conversion of $x to boolean which will evaluate to true as long as $x!=0. If `$x=0`, that statement will actual return true as $x will be false and $x>5 is false so you get `false==false`. If $x=1 to 5, the statement returns false as any non 0 number converts to boolean true. so the statement becomes `true==false`. any number above 5 the statement will return true `true == true`.

Answer (score 2):

It would have been easier to try it yourself.

But anyway, if you don't use break in a case, all the the cases following it will be executed (including the default).

Comment: It's true that there are places other than stackoverflow to figure out the answers to questions, but when we do that no one gets to collect rep ;-)