# Switch evaluations

Tags: php, switch-statement

I recently got into an argument over how `switch` handles comparisons, and need help settling it.

If I write a `switch` such as:

```
switch ($x){
    case ($x > 5):
        echo "foo";
        break;
    case ($x < 5):
        echo "bar";
        break;
    default:
        echo "five";
        break;
}
```

Which `if` statement is it equivalent to? **A** or **B**?

```
// A

if ($x > 5) {
    echo "foo";
} elseif ($x < 5) {
    echo "bar";
} else {
    echo "five";
}

// B

if ($x == ($x > 5)) {
    echo "foo";
} elseif ($x == ($x < 5)) {
    echo "bar";
} else {
    echo "five";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To everyone, let me clarify:

**It is equivalent to `B`.**

It is not "both", it is not sometimes its one, sometimes it is the other, it is always `B`. To understand why you sometimes see results that indicate that it might be `A`, you need to understand [how type coercion works in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

If you pass in a falsey value to the "argument" of `switch` and you use *expressions* in your `case`s that result in a boolean value, they will only match if your expression evaluates to `FALSE`.

---

`switch` is basically a huge `if`/`elseif` tree that performs loose comparisons (`==` instead of `===`) between the value passed to `switch` (the left side of the expression) and the expression in the `case`s (the right side).

This [can be proved](http://codepad.viper-7.com/79Kyvr) quite nicely with a variation on your code:

```
$x = 0;

switch ($x) {
  case $x > -1: // This is TRUE, but 0 == FALSE so this won't match
    echo "case 1";
  case $x == -1: // This is FALSE, and 0 == FALSE so this will match
    echo "case 2";
}
```

And if we convert that to the two `if`/`elseif` trees:

[A](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2vUgNx):

```
$x = 0;

if ($x > -1) {
  // It matches here
  echo "case 1";
} else if ($x == -1) {
  // and not here
  echo "case 2";
}
```

[B](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xogd7U):

```
$x = 0;

if ($x == ($x > -1)) {
  // It doesn't match here
  echo "case 1";
} else if ($x == ($x == -1)) {
  // ..but here instead
  echo "case 2";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That switch case is equivalent to B

**Edit :**

If we take for example that $x is equal to 0 :

$x > 5 will evaluate to false (and 0 evaluates to false too), so the first if will print bar, but the second one will print foo.
        The switch will be transformed to something like this :

```
switch ($x){
    case false:
        echo "foo";
        break;
    case true:
        echo "bar";
        break;
    default:
        echo "five";
        break;
}
```

and that will print foo (same as B)

**Edit 2 :**

I tried it so that gave me :

with $x = 0 => switch (foo), if A (bar), if B (foo)

with $x = 5 => switch (five), if A (five), if B (five)

with $x = 7 => switch (foo), if A (foo), if B (foo)

Comment: I know that it's **B**, but I need more of an explanation than this to settle the argument. Some of the "comments" in the documentation indicate that it might be **A**.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is equivalent to **B**.

If you want to use comparison into your switch (and be equivalent to **A**), you could write this:

```php
switch (true) { // Use true instead of $x
    case ($x > 5):
        echo "foo";
        break;
    case ($x < 5):
        echo "bar";
        break;
    default:
        echo "five";
        break;
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that the above code would be equivalent to **A**?