# Default case always getting executed of Switch

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, switch-statement

I have `Drupal 7` site. I have the following Switch structure.

```
$day = (int)$node->field_hours_count[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
switch ($day) {
    case 1:
        constructNode($node,"sunday");
        echo 'node updated successfuly';
        break;
    case 2:
        constructNode($node,"monday");
        echo 'node updated successfuly';
        break;
    case 3:
        constructNode($node,"tuesday");
        echo 'node updated successfuly';
        break;
    default :
       echo 'no node found'; 
       exit();
   }
```

Here `constructNode()` is a function which accepts two parameters.

```
function constructNode($node,$dayOfWeek)
{
   //core operation
  return $node;
}
```

Issue is suppose $day =1 then `case 1` is executed plus default case. For every value of $day, `default` case is getting executed.

**php - version v 5.5.12**

How do I prevent this?

Comment: What *is* the value of `$day` when the default statement gets executed?

Comment: using `print_r($day)`, I am checking $day & it printing the right value. If passed value is 1 then it prints 1, if 2 then 2 & so on. There is nothing wrong with $day. I have cross-checked it for 2-3 times on it

Comment: I doubt that `field_hours_count` stores the days.

Comment: Your switch is correct. `$day` value is NOT IN (1,2,3).

Comment: Try setting $day manually for testing purposes. Does it work?

Comment: So you're saying in the default case, you're printing `$day` and getting a value of 1,2 or 3?

Comment: @user4035, if that is the case then case 1: should NOT be executed but the issue is that Default  is getting executed along with the right case

Comment: @TZHX, I am printing $day before Switch statement

Comment: @pkhode I tried your code on my machine. Setting $day manually to 1 executes case 1.

Comment: i think `break;` is missing from the default statement.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904108/php-switch-case-default

Comment: @JeesKDenny No need for it.

Comment: What exactly does print_r deliver for $day?

Answer (score 1):

> Issue is suppose `$day = 1` then case 1 is executed plus default case. For every value of `$day`, default case is getting executed.

That's not how `Switch` statements work. After any case is executed, the `break` exits the statement so nothing else will be matched. The only possible way this is happening is if you're calling the `Switch` statement twice with different values.

Comment: Mate, I know that but since I am facing such strange thing hence posted here

Comment: @pkhode no one can magically figure out what you need to fix based on the example you provided (which works perfectly).